# How can I write a controller method in MVC 5 when the incoming notifications have different JSON structures?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webhooks, json-deserialization

I'm attempting to write a webhook receiving service in MVC 5 to receive notifications from the GoToConnect webapi.

The webhook notifications that will be coming from their server have a standard wrapping structure.

```
{
  "source": "messaging",
  "type": "message",
  "content": {object}
}
```

However, the content value can be one of multiple types of notifications that all have different structures which can be identified by the value that comes in the "type" field. My issue is finding a way of doing the model binding when the incoming json structure can be completely different.

If I can get access to the raw json file, I can use a switch statement to manually deserialize the incoming content based on the type value but I've had difficulty finding an easy way to do that. Is there already a way to control the model binding so that I can choose the object that gets created and then lump them together using inheritance or is there an easy way to get the raw json as a parameter to a controller method?

Answer (score 0):

So, with some more research I found an answer to my problem.

First, I created classes for each of the notification content types with an empty marker interface and also a wrapping class containing the Type and an property with that Interface type.

Then, I built a custom model binder by extending the DefaultModelBinder class. In the BindModel method, I used the Type value of the incoming notification to instantiate the specific Notification Content object that I wanted. I stored that object in the Interface type property and then returned it.

Afterwards, I could access that data by casting the Interface Type property to the specific type I wanted in the controller method.